# Question about lagrange's theorem (group theory)

Tags: group-theory

Lagrange's theorem tells us:
$$\frac{\left|G\right|}{\left|H\right|}=\left[G:H\right]$$
(in group theory)
But it is not clear to me what is  the number represents,does it represent the size of subgroup $H$?

Comment: What isn't clear in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)?

Comment: Which number are you about?

Comment: "the ratio ${\displaystyle |G|/|H|}$, as being the index"
the index is the number of subgroups of the group G?

Comment: You're assuming $\lvert G\rvert$ is finite.

Comment: It is the *index*, also sometimes denoted by $(G:H)$, to distinguish it from the field degree $[L:K]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|G|$ and $|H|$ are the orders of the groups $G$ and $H$, respectively, i.e. the number of elements in each. $[G:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $G$, the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$, i.e. the number of unique elements in the set $\{gH:g\in G\}$.

Comment: Thank you! now it's clear